# Handling all errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, handleerror

Good day to all! Trying to solve a problem. I use a method that handles all errors on the site (This method found on the blog of one man)

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    Exception ex = ctx.Server.GetLastError();
    ctx.Response.Clear();

    RequestContext rc = ((MvcHandler)ctx.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;
    IController controller = new CategoryController(); 
    var context = new ControllerContext(rc, (ControllerBase)controller);

    var viewResult = new ViewResult();

    var httpException = ex as HttpException;
    if (httpException != null)
    {
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 404:
                viewResult.ViewName = "Error404";
                break;

            case 500:
                viewResult.ViewName = "Error500";
                break;

            default:
                viewResult.ViewName = "Error";
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        viewResult.ViewName = "Error";
    }

    viewResult.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller"), context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action"));
    viewResult.ExecuteResult(context);
    ctx.Server.ClearError();
}
```

When I start Projects in the studio, causing the error. I get exception at that code:

```
RequestContext rc = ((MvcHandler)ctx.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;
```

**Exception:**

> Unable to cast object of type '`System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler`' to type '`System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler`'

Once I stop debugging (Shift + F5). This method works well and handles any errors. But at the start of project, causing the error. Looking for a solution to these topics, but this problem is not found. Help please.

```
[HandleError]
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
     // some methods
}
```

Comment: Be careful with global variables; even utilizing logging at the global level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved his problem by using code:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Error/404");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Error/Other");
            }
            Server.ClearError();
        }
```